# What is this equation you make when you set 2 circles equal

Tags: geometry

When you set two circles equal, you can rearrange and get  linear equation in terms of $x$ and $y$, now I understand that this linear equation will have the same points of intersection with the two circles as the circles have with each other. Is there a name for this equation, and if so, why is it that we have to re substitute it back into one of the original circles because surely any point $(x,y$) that satisfies the linear equation should also be a point of intersection of the circles, but of course this isn't true as the line is infinitely long

Answer (score 1):

If you have equations of two circles that look like this
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 - r^2 = 0\\
(x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2 - s^2 = 0
$$
then you can equate the two left hand sides, to get
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 - r^2 = (x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2 - s^2 
$$
Indeed, this (generally) reduces to a linear equation that describes a line in the plane. But that's not a line of all points that are on both circles: the points that are also on the circles are those points for which those two values are equal *and they are also both equal to zero*.  All other points, where the two sides of this equation are equal but not equal to zero, describe different points in the plane.

In the special case where your circles have the same radius, i.e. $r = s$, then your line is exactly the line of all points that are equally far away from the centers of both circles.

Edit to address the point in the comment (since it's interesting):

> Why is that when we set two circles equal to one another we are given a line, on which the points of intersection lie, rather than say if we set a quadratic equal to a straight line, we'd get a quadratic which we can solve straightway for the points of intersection, what's the difference that means there is another step to do?

I assume you are talking about the situation where you have
$$
y = ax^2 + bx + c\\
y = dx + e
$$
and you equate the two to get $ax^2 + bx + c = dx + e$, which you then solve, giving you (up to) two $x$-coordinates. (Strictly speaking this is not exactly as we did it above; we can rewrite those equations as $ax^2 + bx + c - y = 0$ and $dx + e - y = 0$, and then equate these two left hand sides, but it gives the same equations once you add $y$.) Let's assume that equation has two solutions and let's call them $x_0, x_1$.

In fact something similar is going on: if we treat the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = dx + e$ as an equation *in the variables $x$ and $y$*, then $x_0$ doesn't stand for a point in the plane, it stands for the entire line $(x_0, y)$ for any $y$-value (and similarly for $x_1$). The only $y$-values which are relevant are those for which the original equations are actually true, i.e. the ones for which $dx + e - y = 0$, i.e. the ones for which $y = dx + e$.

In other words, once you have $x_0, x_1$, to get the intersection points you still have to do $y_0 = dx_0 + e$, and $y_1 = dx_1 + e$ -- that is the same as reducing those lines to single points. But in the case of parabola-line intersection it's so obvious you don't even have to think about it.

Comment: As a consequence, the equation of the obtained line (the radical axis) is the line joining the 2 intersection points, if any, in all cases with unequal or equal radii.

Comment: Why is that when we set two circles equal to one another we are given a line, on which the points of intersection lie, rather than say if we set a quadratic equal to a straight line, we'd get a quadratic which we can solve straightway for the points of intersection, what's the difference that means there is another step to do?

Comment: @Mathguy interesting question, I've updated my answer.

Comment: The way I wagered through it is that the parabola and line are defined for the whole real number line while the circle is only defined for certain values of x, so we sort of have to remove all of the extraneous solutions (which we don't think about with a parabola and line as we know that they're defined for all X)

Comment: @Mathguy that doesn't really justify the result: there are many $x$-values for which the circles are both defined which are none the less extraneous solutions on the line. And anyway extraneous solutions should still come from _somewhere_, they don't magically appear.

Comment: **What's the relation between all the points on the radical axis and the points on the circles then? It's not as simple as if I had y= something and y= something else then I added them together and halved my expression (this would give a line that goes through the mean of the original two y coordinates of each line)

Answer (score 0):

Your "rearranging" steps show that if a point $(x,y)$ is on both circles, then it is also on a certain line $L$. This does not imply that if a point is on $L$, then it's on both circles.

In general, when you derive statements (like equations) from other statements, you're proving logical *implications*, not logical *equivalences*.